# FFMPEG: Two mono to one stereo file whose duration is the longest of those two mono files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Okay, I am trying for some days to find the right ffmpeg command to put two mono files into one stereo file but with one mono to the left channel of the output and the second mono file input to the right channel of the output with output's duration set to longest of those two mono files. To just create what I want without any regards to duration, this command is used:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mka
```

But, as it says in the documentation, duration of the output is default to the shortest of the inputs..but I need the output to have duration of longest input mono file. I have found that this can be done using `amix`command:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest:dropout_transition=3 -ac 2 OUTPUT
```

This sets the output's file duration to longest of input but instead of putting the input1 to left channel and input2 to right channel, it merges them into one and put them in left and right channel. So Left channel=input1+input2; Right channel=input1+input2

How can I make the output's file duration set to longest and have this structure:

```
Left channel=input1
Right channel=input2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `apad` filter to pad the shorter stream and then use `amerge`.

Suppose `left` is shorter, then use

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mka
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find out which one is shorter? Because I have a lot of files that have to be merged into stereo so I can't go manually to check which one...